# RSelenium::rsDriver could not open chrome browser

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I am trying to run this code:

```
client_server <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"), 
                                 chromever="latest", 
                                 port=4444L, 
                                 verbose=F)
```

But, I get this Error:

```
Selenium message:Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'
System info: host: 'XXX.local', ip: 'XXX', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.16', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
     Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
Check server log for further details.
```

I am quite clueless what the solution is here. I tried different ports, that does not seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Try using `chromever = "94.0.4606.41"`. Update `RSelenium` and Chrome.

Comment: Unfortunately this leads to ```Error in chrome_ver(chromecheck[["platform"]], chromever) : version requested doesnt match versions available = 94.0.4606.113,96.0.4664.35```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
Selenium message:Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'
System info: host: 'XXX.local', ip: 'XXX', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.16', java.version: '1.8.0_31'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) server process/service didn't get started/initiated.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using.

---

Though you are using Selenium *Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2'* but your ***`java.version: '1.8.0_31'`*** is *old* and *ancient*.

### Solution

Ensure that *JAVA* / *JDK* is upgraded to current levels [JDK 8u311](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html).

Comment: Thank you. I updated Java / JDK. Still I get errors like: ```Could not open chrome browser. Client error message: Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Operation was aborted by an application callback Check server log for further details.```

Comment: Can you reboot your system and run the test?

Comment: ```client_server <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"), 
                                      chromever="94.0.4606.113", port=4444L, verbose=F)``` was the code

Comment: Why not `chromever="95.0.4638.69"`?

Comment: Because this lead to this error: ```version requested doesnt match versions available = 94.0.4606.113,96.0.4664.35``` although I updated everything